Applying proper paragraph formatting in Word document using Python
I am automating a Word document generation and I would like for it to apply common paragraph formatting. I have used this piece of code to achieve that:
if paragraph.style.name.startswith('Heading'):
    paragraph.paragraph_format.space_before = Pt(12)
    paragraph.paragraph_format.space_after = Pt(6)

else:
    paragraph.paragraph_format.space_before = Pt(0)
    paragraph.paragraph_format.space_after = Pt(0)

This is working fine but tables in the initial pages of the document are moving around and I don't want that to happen.
I have tried to skip tables by using:
if paragraph._element.xpath(".//ancestor::w:tbl"):
    Continue

but that did not work.
I have also tried to skip first few pages by identifying the page breaks but that also did not work.
